# Is there a way to extract an element from a list of functions, before evaluating the numerical value of the function element in Mathematica?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Consider a list of functions

```
M[x_]:={Cos[x], Sin[x], x}
```

Say I want to evaluate the first element

```
M[1][[1]]
```

What Mathematica does is evaluate the entire list at `x=1` then extracts the first element `Cos[1]`. For large list and complicated functions, this is costly as I don't need the rest of the list's elements(for now). Is there a way where I can make Mathematica extract the first element first, then evaluate it at `x=1` instead of the other way around?

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[m, m2]
```

Turn your already defined function that returns a list

```
m[x_] := {Cos[x], Sin[x], x}
```

to a list of functions:

```
m2 = Function /@ m[#];
```

Extract any part using `Part ([[.]])` and use it with the desired input:

```
m2[[2]][z]
```

> Sin[z]

```
m2[[3]][whatever]
```

> whatever